# What are the rules for conversions between various smart pointers in C++

Tags: c++, rules, smart-pointers

The TR1 has introduced shared_ptr, weak_ptr, scoped_ptr and unique_ptr et al.

I would like to know the various conversion/type-promotion rules between these types.

For example what occurs when a scoped_ptr is assigned to a shared_ptr? Are such conversion possible/meaningful and what are some use-cases for such conversions?

*(Is there a table in the specifiction?)*

Answer (score 13):

First, a couple of corrections to your question:

- `scoped_ptr` is a part of Boost and is not included in either C++ TR1 or C++0x (it's expected that in C++0x `unique_ptr` can be used where `scoped_ptr` has been traditionally used).
- `unique_ptr` is not a part of C++ TR1; it is a part of C++0x (since it relies on rvalue references and move semantics, which are only available in C++0x).

To answer your question:  `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` go hand in hand.  An object owned by a `shared_ptr` can also be referenced by a `weak_ptr`.  They are complementary.

A `unique_ptr` has sole ownership of the object it manages; no one else can have ownership of the object.  This is the opposite of the ownership semantics of `shared_ptr`:  with a `unique_ptr`, you have unshared unique ownership; with a `shared_ptr` you have shared, non-unique ownership.

You can construct a `shared_ptr` from a `unique_ptr`; when you do this, the `unique_ptr` loses ownership of the object.  This works because you always know that a given `unique_ptr` is always the only owner of an object, so it is capable of releasing that ownership.

Once an object is owned by a `shared_ptr`, you can't release ownership of the object because there's no guarantee that a given `shared_ptr` is the sole owner of the object.

Comment: @sonicoder:  A `unique_ptr` is noncopyable, just as `scoped_ptr` is noncopyable.  The semantics of `unique_ptr` and `scoped_ptr` are obviously not identical since a `unique_ptr` can be moved, but they are similar and there are very few cases where you would use a `scoped_ptr` but a `unique_ptr` would be undesirable.

Answer (score 3):

Given two classes `A` and `B` (which might be smart pointer types), there are four main ways to convert an instance of type `B` to type `A`:

- <strike>`A` is an accessible base-class object of `B` (e.g. `B` is publicly derived from `A`), and the conversion can slice or simply adjust the type of a reference or pointer.</strike> (intentional strike-through).
- `A` has an accessible constructor taking a `B`.
- `B` has an accessible conversion operator producing an `A`.
- There exists some function that takes a `B` and produces an `A`, and you're calling that function.

For smart pointers inheritance is not used to facilitate conversion, because inheritance allows for incorrect conversions; hence strike-through above. For example, if `SmartPtr<Derived>` inherited publicly from `SmartPtr<Base>`, then one would be able to do `SmartPtr<Base>& spBase = spDerived;`,  and then e.g. `spBase = spOtherDerived`, which would be rather problematic... At a suitably high level of abstraction this is essentially the same problem as for `const` for pointer conversions; see FAQ item [18.17 "Why am I getting an error converting a Foo** → Foo const**?"](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#constptrptr-conversion).

So, smart pointer conversions are generally expressed via the last three bullet points, namely constructors, conversion operators and named conversion functions.

Essentially there are three smart pointers in C++0x, disregarding the deprecated `auto_ptr`:

- `std::unique_ptr` for single objects.
- `std::unique_ptr` for arrays.
- `std::shared_ptr` for single objects.

`unique_ptr` expresses *ownership transfer*, as the old `auto_ptr` did and does. But `auto_ptr` did not support arrays. `unique_ptr` does, and that affects possible conversions.

For single objects, `unique_ptr` supports the conversions that corresponding raw pointers does, via constructors. It has a templated constructor taking a `unique_ptr` of other type. See e.g. C++0x draft N3126 §20.9.10.2.

But, for arrays that would be just as dangerous as with raw pointers! And so for arrays `unique_ptr` does *not* offer base/derived conversion. See e.g. C++0x draft N3126 §20.9.10.3.

Since `unique_ptr` expresses ownership transfer while `shared_ptr` expressed *shared ownership* there can be no safe general conversion from `shared_ptr` to `unique_ptr`. However, the other way, the Boost `shared_ptr` has a constructor taking `auto_ptr`, and the C++0x `shared_ptr` retains this (also has it) and naturally adds a constructor taking `unique_ptr`. See C++0x draft N3126 §20.9.11.2/1.

`shared_ptr` provides base/derived conversions via constructors and via free functions that conceptually implement "casts". Essentially this means that `shared_ptr` is pretty dangerous to use directly for arrays of class type objects. For that use, wrap it.

Converting from `shared_ptr` to `unique_ptr` is, as mentioned, not supported as a general operation. Because shared ownership is not directly compatible with ownership transfer. However, disregarding complications wrt. thread safety, `shared_ptr::unique` tells you whether there is a *single owner* (namely your instance), and then, if you have the requisite knowledge of how the initial `shared_ptr` was constructed, you can use the free function `get_deleter` to get a pointer to the deleter function, and do some low level shenanigans. If you understand completely what I'm talking about here, then fine, good. If not, then it's best that I don't give more details, because this is a very very special case and it requires utmost care and that you Really Know What You're Doing™. ;-)

Well, that's about it. I'm not discussing `weak_ptr`, since it's just part of the `shared_ptr` functionality. But hopefully the above is what you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

1. `scoped_ptr` AFAIK is not part of TR1 (Correct me if I wrong). Generally `boost`'s `scoped_ptr` can't transfer ownership at all. Once you assigned pointer to it, you can't release it.
2. `unique_ptr` can transfer ownership only using `std::move` so it does not transfer ownership as well.
3. `shared_ptr` can't release ownership as other pointers may shared it with. It can be converted to `weak_ptr`. If you try to convert it from `weak_ptr` and the object was released it would throw.
4. `weak_ptr` can be created from `shared_ptr`, when converted to `shared_ptr` it may throw if the object no longer exists.